# Google Calendar API - Deeper insight into calendar usage limits exceeded errors

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I have an application that's been running since 2015. It both reads and writes to approx 16 calendars via a service account, using the Google node.js library (calendar v3 API). We also have G Suite for Education.

The general process is:

- Every 30 seconds it caches all calendar data via a list operation
- Periodically a student will request an appointment "slot", it first checks to see if the slot is still open (via a list call) then an insert.

That's all it does. It's been running fine until the past few days, where API `insert` calls started failing:

```
{
    "code": 403,
    "errors": [{
        "domain": "usageLimits",
        "reason": "quotaExceeded",
        "message": "Calendar usage limits exceeded."
    }]
}
```

This isn't all that special - the documentation has three "solutions":

> - Read more on the Calendar usage limits in the G Suite Administrator
>     help.
> - If one user is making a lot of requests on behalf of many users
>     of a G Suite domain, consider using a Service Account with authority
>     delegation (setting the quotaUser parameter).
> - Use exponential backoff.

1. I'm not exceeding any of the stated limits as far as I can tell.
2. While I'm using a service account, it isn't making a request on behalf of a user. The service account has write access to the calendar and adds the user as an attendee
3. Finally, I do not think exponential backoff will help, although I do not have this implemented. The time between a request to insert and the next insert call is measured in seconds, not milliseconds. Additionally, just running calls directly on the command line with a simple script produce the same problem.

Some stats:

```
2015 - 2,466 inserts, 186 errors
2016 - 25,747 inserts, 237 errors
2017 - 42,815 inserts, 225 errors
2018 - 41,390 inserts, 1,074 errors (990 of which are in the past 3 days)
```

I have updated the code over the years, but it has remained largely untouched this term.

At this point I'm unsure what to do - there is no channel to reach Google, and while I have not implemented a backoff strategy, the way timings work with this application, subsequent calls are delayed by seconds, and processed in a queue that sequentially processes requests. The only concurrent requests would be list operations.

Comment: I'm having same problem using java-sdk. I am running my application since February 2018, and the problem started at December 11 2018 AM 5:40 UTC and not fixed yet. I asked the GSuite support team and got an answer that it might be fixed within 2-3 days.

Comment: BTW, I created a new G Suite account (not user) and tried the same thing with it, 
first it took about 20 hours getting rid of 404 (not found) errors 
then it SUCCEEDED  a couple of times,
but then it started to fail with same "limit exceeded" errors.
Now, it failes with 404 (not found) errors again. 
I think that I really need to implement OAuth instead of using Service Account.

Comment: The "first" problem for me started at Dec 11 2018 3:11 UTC. As an interim step I created a new project under our "domain" account (instead of my "personal" account), new service account, and it worked for a few hours, but at some point in the day it started getting errors. I then swapped between the accounts a few times (I know, horrible practice) to keep things running. Right now I haven't seen any errors since yesterday.